# finding problem while using email ext plugin in jenkins pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am using email ext plugin my Jenkins pipeline job like this::::::

```
emailext body: "(body: ${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL}", recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']], subject: "Jenkins Build ${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME}", to: '<some emailid>'
```

Its working but not getting any email from Jenkins.
but output is showing sending to  ---> what i gave [to] option...
Pls help me out
TIA

Comment: try to add your email-address in "to:" section at the end.

Comment: i added email but security purpose not showing here, Thanks, any way i solved my problem